# use only one element from class jQuery UI

Tags: jquery

How can i change current button(that clicked), not all buttons on page,where shold i put "this" element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = "blind";
      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // some effects have required parameters
      // run the effect
      $( ".button" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 1000);

    }; 
    // set effect from select menu value   
    $('.moreshide').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('oks');
      runEffect();
    });
  });           
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass reference of clicked element to your runEffect function. Then find the closest section id and button class inside the section.

```
function runEffect(obj) {
  // get effect type from
  var selectedEffect = "blind";
  // most effect types need no options passed by default
  var options = {};
  // some effects have required parameters
  // run the effect
  $(obj).closest('#chef').find(".button").toggle(selectedEffect, options, 1000);                    
}; 

$('.moreshide').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('oks');
      runEffect(this);
});
```

Comment: im sorry maybe i had wrong question, i need not only one, but current that i clicked

Comment: @ДенисМогила, Kindly share your HTML part.

Comment: <section id="chef">
   <div class="text">
   <h2 class="title">Шеф - повар</h2>
   <p>lorem ipsu,</p>
   <p class="moreshide"> lorem ipsum</p>
 <div class="button">Читать далее</div>
   </div>

Comment: can i use this instead .eq(0)?

Comment: its helpfull for only first element, how can i make for element that i click?

Comment: Could you explain why its working with parametr of the function?

Comment: @ДенисМогила, Glad to help you.